# Connecting an azure website to an azure VM

Tags: azure

I have an azure website which talks to an azure VM

I have set it up following the article below:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/

But when I got my last bill I noticed I was being charged for running this connection.

[image]

This seems like an awful lot just to connect two things I'm already paying for together, so I think I must be doing something wrong.

From what it looks like im being charged for this connection as if it were a site to site vpn.

Have I done something wrong? Is this what I should be expecting? Is there a cheaper way?

Comment: It sounds like you _did_ set up a site-to-site VPN gateway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton is there an alternate way of connecting a vm to a website that doesn't cost as much?

Comment: The article you're referring is about how to _"build hybrid solutions with your Azure and on-premise resources"_. Azure VM has a name that your Web App can use.

Comment: @user272735 im not sure what you mean, the article is about connecting a site to a VN *'Integrate a web app with an Azure Virtual Network'* which is what ive done, It also contains some info about how to use that to connect to on prem (which i think is the site to site arrow on the diagram) which I have **not** done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: correct answer is below:**

The article is misleading.

If you want to avoid the charges you mentioned above, you will have to:

- Create a Vnet.
- Place your VM in that Vnet.
- Create your website inside that Vnet too.

Machines inside a VM communicate freely as if inside a single LAN.

The article assumes that you have two different Vnets and you're connecting them using Site-to-Site VPN, its'll cost you around 27 USD to use a VPN gateway plus traffic, this is all good if you have a specific requirement to keep the website hosted away from the VM, and in your case I don't see a reason to.

To better understand Vnet's and figure out your next steps, I'd recommend that you start reading here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156007.aspx

**Correct Answer**

It seems that my answer above was not correct, here's an updated one:

Apparently, Azure Website (or Web Apps), cannot be placed inside a Vnet, and the only way for it to communicate with VMs hosted inside a Vnet as if they're inside a single LAN would be to create a Point-to-Site VPN session. just like you did. this will cause you to pay the VPN fees each month. More Informaiton here: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/15/azure-websites-virtual-network-integration/

Another way for you to do it, is to allow communication over the VM EndPoint and secure it with ACLs, this should do the job nicely and will let you avoid using a VPN gateway, but not all protocols are supported: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/

My apology for the confusion, I should have done my research first before answering.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This sounds exactly like what I want, I have the new vnet and my VM is inside that network which is good. But how do I create my website in that VNet, there doesn't seem to be any options to do with network in the UI. When i try to add the existing site to the VNet in the UI it says `The virtual network must have a point to site VPN enabled` which I assume is what was causing the charges in the first place. Is there a way to actually create the website inside that new VNet?

Comment: thanks, its a bit weird that an expensive vpn is the only way to do this.